# How do I add a reference to a generated TextBox in the control tree?

Tags: c#, .net, asp-classic, textbox

I have an input field that is appended to the HTML in a div.
I need to have this input field bound to the `ctrlmenuItems` in the system but I don't know how.

I have this function which is the one calling the object:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
  int Id = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["edit"]);
  DA.page itmToEdit = DA.page.StaticGetById(Id);
  itmToEdit.title = ctrltitle.Text;
        itmToEdit.menuItems = ctrlmenuItems.Text;
  itmToEdit.content = ctrlcontent.Text;
  itmToEdit.Update();
  UpdateGUI();
  pnlEditArea.Visible = false;
}
```

I tried using:

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox ctrlmenuItems;
```

which just creates a null reference.

I tried calling this `onInit()`:

```
TextBox ctrlmenuItems = new TextBox();
ctrlmenuItems.ID = "ctrlmenuItems";
ctrlmenuItems.Text = "Enter your name";
this.form1.Controls.Add(ctrlmenuItems);
```

with no luck.

The appending is done like this:

```
litMenu.Text += string.Format(@"<div>
      <a class='button' href='?del={1}'>Slet</a>
      <input name='ctrlmenuItems' type='text' id='ctrlmenuItems' value'{0}' />
    </div>",
  itm.menuItems,
  itm.id);
```

I need to be able to click "save" and it passes on the value from the textField to dataAccess
but I can't figure out how to bind this "virtual" textbox correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` tags with a `name` attribute will be stored in the `Request.Form` array when the page posts back.

Whether you add the `TextBox` control manually, or simply insert the corresponding HTML (which I would not recommend, building HTML via string concatenation makes it very easy to yield invalid HTML), you can retrieve the value when your button is clicked using the following:

```
string value = Request.Form["ctrlmenuItems"];
```